# How does session.clear() work in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session

I referred many articles but I am still not clear on what `session.clear` perform in hibernate.

According to what I came across so far is,
When we use batch save / update as shown below:

```
Session session = SessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Employee employee = new Employee(.....);
    session.save(employee);
    if( i % 50 == 0 ) { // Same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

`sesion.flush();` is used in flushing the session forces Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database.

**Question**

**1.** After flushing the session, why is it necessary to do `session.clear()`? Is it really required?

**2.** Will `session.clear()` perform commit action?

**3.** If `session.clear()` evicts all loaded objects, what happens internally while commit and rollback actions are performed?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Think of the Session as a cache of entities you have already loaded from (or persisted to) the database since you've started the current transaction.

1. `Session.clear` is not mandatory in any way, but is useful if you do a lot of entity loading/saving within one transaction, to avoid getting out of memory error. In your example, you'll have 50 `employee` entities replicated in the session. Without the `flush` and `clear` method call every 50 `save()`, you would have had 100.000 entities replicated in the session (and not garbage collectable, because the session has a link to the entity).
2. `Session.clear` will not perform commit nor rollback. Not even a `flush` (hence why you should do flush before a `Session.clear`, so that hibernate generates sql queries for pending entities updates).
3. Rollback or commit actions are not performed on the application side, but in the database: hibernate will just ask the database to commit or rollback (Hibernate might trigger a flush before the commit action, but the flush is not part of the commit). The commit action will not (and can't) access the session. It is a database internal mechanism that will persist (or revert) the data modification performed thanks to all SQL queries run since the start of the transaction.

In exactly the same way, opening a transaction in hibernate is not performing a lot of things: mainly getting a db connection out of the pool, and telling the database to *NOT* `auto_commit` the following sql queries but to wait for a commit or rollback command.

Answer (score -2):

The answer of Thierry is very nice. But if the client has tooo many concurrent connections and memory problems(GC). The best solution was that I did here: without hibernate directly using native JDBC connector of mysql or postgres.

Comment: Direct jdbc usage still requires connections to db and memory. Too many concurrent connections and/or too much memory usage will also happen with direct jdbc use if the developper is not careful enough ;)

Comment: better than hibernate.  Hibernate has alot of problems. 15K connections that I have now, without problems. If I do this with Hibernate,   -> Tomcat Crashes.

Comment: why do you have 15k connections? my guess would be - you need only one and share it. Connection should be a singleton.

Comment: @TomášJohanPrítrský  :  PLease read Thread safety and JDBC connections and singletons.