# When is hibernate first level cache cleared?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am kind of confused about when the first level cache of a (hibernate session?) is cleared in a spring application. I am running a very long job which reads a lot of data and at some point the app runs out of memory. 
I am assuming cached object are causing the problem.

Initially i thought closing a transaction will force the cache to be cleared and reading entries from the database one by one inside a `@Transactional(propagation=REQUIRES_NEW)` method should fix the problem. 
But unfortunately the application still runs out of memory.
The whole code might run inside a transaction already. Does hibernate use the same cache / session for multiple or nested transactions?
All my selects are done with spring repository calls (So i am not using the entity manager directly).
Is the only way to clear the cache by calling session.clear() manually or having the last parent transaction closing?

Comment: Please try reading some answers first to get some insight on your problem: Here is a suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969763/how-does-session-clear-work-in-hibernate

Comment: The `Session` or `EntityManager` IS the first level cache. It won't be cleared unless you explicitly tell it to do so by calling `clear`.

Comment: @rbento Thank you the link helped me a little bit

Comment: @M. Deinum Okay but in my understanding there is only one entity manager in the whole application. So my question should be when spring decides to clear this cache?

Comment: Seems like the problem was fixed by running the code by a task executor instead of the http request handling thread itself.

Comment: There are `EntityManager` instances per thread not 1 for the whole application. There is 1 `EntityManagerFactory`.  Doing this in the background isn't a solution as the same problem still persists but you probably evaded issues with it currently until your data grows. The real solution is to flush and clear at regular intervals.

Comment: This makes me curious. If there is one entity manager per thread, how can spring inject the entity manager into a service? I am not sure anymore if the memory leak was related to the cache. I am guessing that somehow the gc did not collect the objects from the handling thread which was in a weird state due to a timeout from a proxy (Although i have no idea if this can really happen).

Comment: As far as i know, First level cache will work for same transaction and nested transaction. But still if its your necessity to have these configuration then you may use evict() method. This will remove the object from first level cache. You can call this method for unwanted object. reference link https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-session-evict-and-merge-example